# Losing the data in the header when nginx is used in between the java application

Tags: java, nginx, websocket

I am trying to access my java project through localhost, the data in the header retains. So the following methods works fine. Websocket is getting opened.

```
if (!headerContainsToken(req, "upgrade", "websocket")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return;
   }
private boolean headerContainsToken(HttpServletRequest req,
        String headerName, String target) {
    Enumeration<String> headers = req.getHeaders(headerName);
    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String header = headers.nextElement();
        String[] tokens = header.split(",");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (target.equalsIgnoreCase(token.trim())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is my nginx configuration of my application

```
server {
listen test:80;
server_name  test;
root /home/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/;

location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

But when the same application is hit through nginx, then the above method returns **Bad request**.
So i have no idea where the data in the header gone, when is hit through nginx. And the websocket is not opening at all.

Any suggestions plz

Comment: You should edit your question and add your `nginx` configuration.

Comment: i added nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some more headers to your `nginx` configuration to proxy WebSockets. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html).

Add this to the `http` container of your `nginx` configuration:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

And change your `location` block to this:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

If you need to add the `X-` headers too, they need some values. Such as:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Other predefined variables are [listed here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).